# How to implement cloud messaging firebase in react native app?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement cloud messaging firebase in react native app, I follow a lot of tutorials but non of them works fine like :

https://medium.com/@rempire230/push-notification-for-android-in-react-native-282019867f86

https://medium.com/@anum.amin/react-native-integrating-push-notifications-using-fcm-349fff071591

The android app always crash when receiving a message in foreground or background.

I would be grateful If anybody can recommend a good tutorial about using FCM in react native (for both android and ios).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ive used the second article and ive implemented it, and it works smooth. Whats the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

I have found this tutorial and it works fine for android and ios:

React Native #31: Firebase Notification (react-native-firebase Version 7)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyAwv9HLS60&t=805s
https://github.com/tranhonghan/RNFirebaseV7/